# Change deleting method for updating core data attribute

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, nsmanagedobjectcontext

after a while I am now able to delete a core data record from a table view after a long-press action on a selected row. According to my apps requirements, I don't want to permanent delete the record, I only want to mark the record as deleted, therefore I have created an attribute named ToDoStatus, which I want to update and change it contents to 'Marked as deleted' when the user executes a long-press action on the selected row.
Here you have the code as it is now (deletes the row permanently).
You are kindly requested to show me the way to change the value of the content of the attribute inside the handleLongPress method:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "AddToDoViewController.h"
#import "EditToDoViewController.h"
#import "MenuViewController.h"



@interface RootViewController ()
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end


@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize fetchedResultsController, managedObjectContext,AddToDoButton,MenuToDoButton;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {

  [super viewDidLoad];
//  [self setTitle:@"Today"];
  [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:[self editButtonItem]];
    self.editButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UILabel *lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    lblTitle.text = @"Today";
    lblTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    lblTitle.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lblTitle.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    lblTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy" size:25.0];
    [lblTitle sizeToFit];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = lblTitle;



    [self.editButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy" size:20], NSFontAttributeName,
                                     [UIColor blueColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                     nil]
                           forState:UIControlStateNormal];







    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;


  NSError *error = nil;
  if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error])
  {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
  }
}
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSManagedObject *managedObject = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];





  [[cell textLabel] setText:[[managedObject valueForKey:@"estado"] description]];
  NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[managedObject valueForKey:@"todoYear"] description]];
    UIButton *urgentButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 25, 18, 18)];

    [urgentButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"urgent"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:urgentButton];

    UIButton *yellowButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(305, 5, 10, 40)];

    [yellowButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Red"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:yellowButton];

    UIButton *doneButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(33, 27, 18, 18)];

    [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alldone"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:doneButton];

    UIButton *doneButton2 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(53, 27, 18, 18)];

    [doneButton2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alldone"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:doneButton2];



    UIButton *doneButton3 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(71, 27, 18, 18)];

    [doneButton3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"urgent"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:doneButton3];


    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:@"  "];
  [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy" size:22.0f];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy" size:15.0f];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    EditToDoViewController *detailViewController = [[EditToDoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditToDoViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    detailViewController.selectedObject = selectedObject;
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

    [self presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}




#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  return [[fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
  return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil)
  {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                   reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];
  }

    //long press

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                          initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1.00;
    //seconds
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];




  [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

  return cell;
}


-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
    if (indexPath == nil)
        NSLog(@"long press on table view but not on a row");
    else
    {

        if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
            NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded");
            //Do Whatever You want on End of Gesture
        }
        else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Announcement" message: @"You have long-pressed the row...!" delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan.");


            NSManagedObjectContext *context = [fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
            [context deleteObject:[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
            NSLog(@"long press on table view at row %d", indexPath.row);

            // Update ToDoStatus
            NSError *error1 = nil;
            if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error1])
            {
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error1, [error1 userInfo]);
                abort();
            }
            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![context save:&error])
            {
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();
            }
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            //Do Whatever You want on Began of Gesture
        }

    }
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
  {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    [context deleteObject:[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
      NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
      abort();
    }
      NSError *error1 = nil;
      if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error1])
      {
          NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error1, [error userInfo]);
          abort();
      }
      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"To-Do Deleted" message: @"You have marked To-Do as deleted...!" delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [alert show];
      [alert release];
      [self.tableView reloadData];
  }   
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath 
      toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath;
{  
  NSMutableArray *things = [[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] mutableCopy];

  // Grab the item we're moving.
  NSManagedObject *thing = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath];

  // Remove the object we're moving from the array.
  [things removeObject:thing];
  // Now re-insert it at the destination.
  [things insertObject:thing atIndex:[destinationIndexPath row]];

  // All of the objects are now in their correct order. Update each
  // object's displayOrder field by iterating through the array.
  int i = 0;
  for (NSManagedObject *mo in things)
  {
    [mo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i++] forKey:@"displayOrder"];
  }

  [things release], things = nil;

  [managedObjectContext save:nil];
}






#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Fetched results controller
- (IBAction)AddToDoAction:(id)sender {

    AddToDoViewController *viewController = [[AddToDoViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
#pragma mark Fetched results controller
- (IBAction)MenuToDoAction:(id)sender {

    MenuViewController *viewController = [[MenuViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
  if (fetchedResultsController) return fetchedResultsController;

  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  NSEntityDescription *entity = 
               [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FavoriteThing" 
                           inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

  [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

  NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = 
              [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"displayOrder" 
                                          ascending:YES];

  NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] 
                              initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];



    NSNumber *yearBuscado = @2013;
    NSNumber *mesBuscado = @12;
    NSNumber *diaBuscado = @13;
    NSString *tipourgente = @"Urgent";
    NSString *tipocolor = @"Yellow";
    NSPredicate *yearPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"todoYear == %@", yearBuscado];
    NSPredicate *monthPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"todoMonth == %@", mesBuscado];
    NSPredicate *dayPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"todoDay == %@", diaBuscado];
    NSPredicate *urgentPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"urgent == %@", tipourgente];
    NSPredicate *colorPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"color == %@", tipocolor];

  [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];






  NSPredicate *busqueda = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[yearPredicate, monthPredicate,dayPredicate,urgentPredicate]];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:busqueda];
  NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController =
              [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                                  managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
                                                    sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
  aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
  [self setFetchedResultsController:aFetchedResultsController];


  [aFetchedResultsController release];
  [fetchRequest release];
  [sortDescriptor release];
  [sortDescriptors release];


  return fetchedResultsController;
}    

- (void)dealloc {
  [fetchedResultsController release];
  [managedObjectContext release];


  [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: It would be just like changing any attribute value on any object. Which part do you not understand?

Comment: `[[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] setValue:@"Gone" forKey:@"ToDoStatus"]`

Comment: @Wain, would you mind posting your proposal as Answer for my question, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you currently have `deleteObject:`, replace with:

```
[[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] setValue:@"Gone" forKey:@"ToDoStatus"]
```

that is all.